# Inno Setup to match and replace exact strings in a file

Tags: inno-setup

I have a batch file wherein I set the java path as

**For 32 bit**

```batch
set JRE_HOME=%INSTALL_DIR%\java
```

**and for 64 bit**

```batch
set JRE_HOME=%INSTALL_DIR%\java_x64
```

these values are in multiple lines. I need to replace these lines as following

`set JRE_HOME=%INSTALL_DIR%\java` **To** `set JRE_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\java`

**and**

`set JRE_HOME=%INSTALL_DIR%\java_x64` **To** `set JRE_HOME=C:\Program Files\java`

**Problems with my code**

- When searching for string `set JRE_HOME=%INSTALL_DIR%\java` and replacing it with  `set JRE_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\java` , it matches the second string as well, i.e `set JRE_HOME=%INSTALL_DIR%\java_x64` and replace it like `JRE_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\java_x64`
- **I want my code to match exact string i.e** `set JRE_HOME=%INSTALL_DIR%\java` not `set JRE_HOME=%INSTALL_DIR%\java_x64`
- Is there a way we can achieve this? Please help.

**[Code]**

```pascal
function FileReplaceString(const FileName, SearchString, ReplaceString: string): Boolean;
var
  MyFile : TStrings;
  MyText : string;
begin
  MyFile := TStringList.Create;

  try
    result := true;

    try
      MyFile.LoadFromFile(FileName);
      MyText := MyFile.Text;

      { Only save if text has been changed. }
      if StringChangeEx(MyText, SearchString, ReplaceString, True) > 0 then
      begin;
        MyFile.Text := MyText;
        MyFile.SaveToFile(FileName);
      end;
    except
      result := false;
    end;
  finally
    MyFile.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
var
  Java32,Java64: string;
  JREVersion:integer;
begin
  if CurStep = ssDone then
  begin
    JREVersion := 32;

    if JREVersion = 32 then
    begin
      Java32 := ExpandConstant('{pf}') + '\java';
      if FileReplaceString(
           ExpandConstant('D:\authorized\Builds\Solo\custom.bat'),
           'set JRE_HOME=%INSTALL_DIR%\java',
           'set JRE_HOME=' + Java32) 
      then
        MsgBox('Java32 path has been set!', mbInformation, MB_OK)
      else  
        MsgBox('Java32 path has not been set!.', mbError, MB_OK)
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: So why don't you change the batch file template not to use the same token for two different paths?

Comment: Thanks @MartinPrikryl for your response but this is not something I can change or under my control. That's why I was looking for a different way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace only the instances that end with a new line:

```pascal
FileReplaceString(
  ExpandConstant('D:\authorized\Builds\Solo\custom.bat'),
  'set JRE_HOME=%INSTALL_DIR%\java'#13#10,
  'set JRE_HOME='+Java32+#13#10)
```